# Como saber si un resultset esta vacío en java?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statements

Necesito una forma de saber si el resultset que obtengo de una consulta a la base de datos está vacío o si tiene valores. Intenté con el siguiente código pero termina entrando siempre al if sin importar si tengo o no un registro en la base de datos.

```
   PreparedStatement statement=DatabaseManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(OBTENER_GENERACION);
                    statement.setString(1, nombreUsuario);
                    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
                    if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) //verifica si esta vacio, pero desplaza el puntero al siguiente elemento
                    {
                        tieneGen=false;
                    mU.setGeneracion(nombreUsuario);
                    MenuEstudiante mE = new MenuEstudiante();
                    mE.setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("No tiene gen");  
    
                    }
                    else {
                        tieneGen=true;
                    MenuEstudiante mE = new MenuEstudiante();
                    mE.setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Tiene generacion");
                    }
    
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
    
                return tieneGen;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueuba con rs.next. Yo lo uso para recorrer los result set y con un while y devuelve true siempre que tenga siguiente valor

```
PreparedStatement statement=DatabaseManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(OBTENER_GENERACION);
                        statement.setString(1, nombreUsuario);
                        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
                        if (!rs.next() ) //verifica si esta vacio, pero desplaza el puntero al siguiente elemento
                        {
                            tieneGen=false;
                        mU.setGeneracion(nombreUsuario);
                        MenuEstudiante mE = new MenuEstudiante();
                        mE.setVisible(true);
                        System.out.println("No tiene gen");  
        
                        }
                        else {
                            tieneGen=true;
                        MenuEstudiante mE = new MenuEstudiante();
                        mE.setVisible(true);
                        System.out.println("Tiene generacion");
                        }
        
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
        
                    return tieneGen;
                }
```

Comment: Tu solución es válida, pero tiene un problema: si el `ResultSet` contiene datos, al llamar a `next` estás avanzando el cursor, por lo cual si deseas consumir los datos del `ResultSet` luego de avanzar con `next` tocará rebobinarlo. Para estos casos y cuando el `ResultSet` aún no ha sido consumido, es mejor usar [`isBeforeFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst--). Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias no lo sabia‍‍

Answer (score -3):

```
if (rs.next()) {
                
    do {
        //contenido

    } while(rs.next());
                
} else {
    //esta vacio el resultset
    
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos. 
ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.